# Delete or edit element from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, contextmenu

I have an arraylist where having a long click on an element, It shows a context menu where I can remove or edit the selected item of the arraylist.

The doubt that I have is, how I define which item I'm selecting, to edit or remove it?

These are the methods referred to the context menu. Is the first time I'm using this menu and I haven't tested yet the functionality, so these methods may be wrong.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit_travel:

            return true;
        case R.id.delete_travel:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

As I said, I think that is missing the way to determine which element of the arraylist I want to edit or delete, but I don't know how to define this

**UPDATE -- added code**

```
public class TravelListActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_TRAVEL = 0;
private TravelAdapter adapter;

private class TravelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TravelInfo>{

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<TravelInfo> travels;
    private static final int RESOURCE = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2;

    public TravelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TravelInfo> travels) {
        super(context, RESOURCE, travels);

        this.context = context;
        this.travels = travels;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinearLayout view;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null){
            view = new LinearLayout(context);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(RESOURCE, view, true);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            view = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        TravelInfo info = travels.get(position);
        holder.text1.setText(info.getCity() + " (" + info.getCountry() + ")");
        holder.text2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.year) + " " + info.getYear());

        return view;
    }

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Comment: Post code which contains Arraylist initialization.

Comment: post the code for the where you set the `longClickListener` and the code of the `onLongClick`

Comment: I added more code... mmm, I haven't implemented those methods, as said, not sure about how to use the context menu yet

Comment: have u init listview or set adapter for listview?

Comment: I think that I've set an adapter, sorry but I'm still learning about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `item` which is long pressed by the following lines:

```
TravelInfo itemSelected = adapter.getItem(info.position);
```

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    TravelInfo itemSelected = adapter.getItem(info.position);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit_travel:

            return true;
        case R.id.delete_travel:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

*Note: For this to work (1) you should have initialized `adapter` in the `onCreate` (2) set the list adapter by calling `setAdapter(adapter)`*

Answer (score 0):

you can get the position of selected row of listview:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.edit_travel:
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "edit: "+info.position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
       case R.id.delete_travel:
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "delete: "+info.position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
                             }
            return false;
        }
```

After getting position remove / Update it from your Arraylist at that position .
Now, call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) ::  `youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`